# Haskell: class instance with class type parameters

Tags: haskell

Good day. I'm new to Haskell. One thing is not clear for me concerning declaring and instantiating some custom classes.

1. There is a standard class `Integral` in haskell. According to the hackage, `Integral` declares the mandatory method `quot :: a -> a -> a`. So it means that every instance of that class should have this method implementation, right?
2. We can declare some function, using Integral as an argument, like:

```hs
proba :: (Integral a) => a -> a -> a
proba x y = x `quot` y
```

So far so good

3. Now lets declare our own class Proba:

```hs
class Proba a where
    proba :: a -> a -> a
```

I can implement an Int or Integer (or other data type) instance like this:

```hs
instance Proba Integer where
    proba x y = x `quot` y

instance Proba Int where
    proba x y = x `quot` y
```

But I don't want to. **I want one instance for every Integral.** But when I try to do it, I get an error:

```hs
instance (Integral a) => Proba a where
    proba x y = x `quot` y

 Illegal instance declaration for `Proba a'
   (All instance types must be of the form (T a1 ... an)
    where a1 ... an are *distinct type variables*,
    and each type variable appears at most once in the instance head.
    Use FlexibleInstances if you want to disable this.)
 In the instance declaration for `Proba a'
```

Ok, it seems that it asks me for *distinct type variables* instead of classes. But why?! Why isn't it enough for it just to have an `Integral` here? Since `quot` is declared for every `Integral`, this instance should be valid for every `Integral`, shoudn't it?

Maybe there is a way to achieve the same effect?

Comment: `Use FlexibleInstances if you want to disable this.` Have you tried doing that?

Comment: I'll definitely do this, but what I wonder is why this stuff is hidden behind some custom option and not available by default?

Comment: Because reasons; this is technically an extension to how language works by default. You can read about all of those [here](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.2/html/users_guide/ghc-language-features.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the error message indicates, you can use `FlexibleInstances` (a fairly common and safe extension) to allow this behavior, but you'll also need `UndecidableInstances`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

class Proba a where
    proba :: a -> a -> a

instance Integral a => Proba a where
    proba = quot
```

The reason why this isn't enabled by default is because it's specifically a GHC extension, and it is not part of the Haskell98 specification.  You'll find that there are a lot of language extensions that are very useful and safe to use, and often times you only want them enabled in particular modules.  Instead of just asking "why isn't this default", also ask "when would I not want this to be default?".

---

Another way to implement this without extensions is to encode the type class directly as a data type:

```
data Proba a = Proba
    { proba :: a -> a -> a
    }

integralProba :: Integral a => Proba a
integralProba = Proba quot
```

Then you can pass it around as

```
foldProba :: Proba a -> a -> [a] -> a
foldProba p = foldr (proba p)
```

Then if you have `foldProba integralProba`, then it automatically constrains the type to `Integral a => a -> [a] -> a`.

Comment: Much thanks to you, it is all clear now. About the question "when would I not want this to be default?" - well I thought that it is quite common: if we can do such magic with functions, then why shoudn't we can do the same with classes? Anyway - this solution is good for me.

Comment: @skapral These are not the same thing though.  With the `Integral a => Proba a` instance, you could also define a specific `Proba Int` instance where `proba` has different behavior than the one using `Int`'s `Integral` instance.  That's what the `UndecidableInstances` is for.

Comment: @skapral See my edits for an alternate implementation that lets you avoid the language extensions and uses only Haskell98 code to do so.  Then you can easily have an `integralProba`, an `intProba`, an `integerProba`, and more that all have different behaviors as needed, or even `intProba1` and `intProba2` that haev the type `Proba Int` but different behaviors.

Comment: I had no idea it was possible to do this now. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid [this talk](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/MDCC-TechTalk-Classes-Jim-but-not-as-we-know-them) by SPJ that explains it well how type classes work, and basically all type classes act as an implicit argument that gets passed in by the compiler.  This argument is just a vector table of all the functions in the type class, so you'll have the `num_Int` vector table for `Int`'s instance of `Num`, and so on.  However, while typeclasses are very useful in much of Haskell, I'm finding more and more that I've used them too often instead of just using a table of functions.